# JAXB/MOXy Adapting an XMLElementWrapper

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to use JAXB/MOXy to map a domain represented by a set of interfaces with a distinctive characteristic: all multivalued elements are encapsulated with `Iterables` as opposed to arrays or `Collection`s. Below is a toy example to demonstrate my case.

**Actor.java (note the use of `Iterable<Movie>`)**

```
package test.moxy;

public interface Actor {

    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);

    public Iterable<Movie> getMovies();
    public void setMovies(Iterable<Movie> movies);

}
```

**Movie.java**

```
package test.moxy;

public interface Movie {

    public String getTitle();
    public void setTitle(String title);

}
```

**Main class**

```
package test.moxy;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class TestBinding {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException {

        Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[] { Actor.class, Movie.class };

        List<String> mappings = new ArrayList<String>();
        mappings.add("test/moxy/oxm.xml");

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, mappings);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(types, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream("src/main/java/test/moxy/input.xml"));
        Actor actor = (Actor) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(actor, System.out);

    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actor>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <movies>
        <movie>
            <title>Smith's Trilogy - Part I</title>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <title>Smith's Trilogy - Part II</title>
        </movie>
        <movie>
            <title>Smith's Trilogy - Part III</title>
        </movie>
    </movies>
</actor>
```

**oxm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="test.moxy" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Actor">
        <xml-root-element name="actor" />
            <xml-type prop-order="name movies" factory-class="test.moxy.ProxyFactory"
                factory-method="initActor" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="name" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="movies" name="movie" >
                    <xml-element-wrapper name="movies" />
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Movie">
            <xml-root-element name="movie" />
            <xml-type factory-class="test.moxy.ProxyFactory"
                factory-method="initMovie" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="title" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

`ProxyFactory` is a standard factory such as the one exemplified in http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html

As it stands, I get the following `JAXBException`: Exception Description: `XmlElementWrapper` is only allowed on a collection or array property but [movies] is not a collection or array property.

I tried with an `XMLAdapter` on movies to convert between `Iterable<T>` and `List<T>`, but it seems to apply to every `movie` element, as opposed to the `movies` wrapper. I was wondering if and how I could specify such a thing as some sort of `XMLAdapter` for wrappers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception states you're not going to be able to map a property of type `Iterable` with `@XmlElementWrapper`.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: XmlElementWrapper is only allowed on a collection or array property but [movies] is not a collection or array property.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50015] (Eclipse Persistence Services - @VERSION@.@QUALIFIER@): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: XmlElementWrapper is only allowed on a collection or array property but [movies] is not a collection or array property.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:182)
```

**XmlAdapter (MoviesAdapter)**

Instead we are going to use an `XmlAdapter` to convert `Iterable` into something we can map.  In this case an instance of a class we'll make up called `Movies` that has a `List` of `Movie` instances.

```
package test.moxy;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MoviesAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MoviesAdapter.Movies, Iterable<Movie>> {

    public static class Movies {
        public List<Movie> movie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Movie> unmarshal(Movies v) throws Exception {
        return v.movie;
    }

    @Override
    public Movies marshal(Iterable<Movie> v) throws Exception {
        Movies movies = new Movies();
        for(Movie movie : v) {
            movies.movie.add(movie);
        }
        return movies;
    }

}
```

**External Metadata (oxm.xml)**

Below is the modified `oxm.xml` that references the `XmlAdapter`.  With the new mappings the `Movies` object will cause the `movies` element to come into existence so we won't need the `@XmlElementWrapper` metadata anymore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="test.moxy" xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Actor">
        <xml-root-element name="actor" />
            <xml-type prop-order="name movies" factory-class="test.moxy.ProxyFactory"
                factory-method="initActor" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="name" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="movies">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="test.moxy.MoviesAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Movie">
            <xml-root-element name="movie" />
            <xml-type factory-class="test.moxy.ProxyFactory"
                factory-method="initMovie" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="title" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```